# Item property in Slides object in C#

Tags: c#, interop

I am trying to make a function to collect every titles of my PowerPoint presentation in C#.
First I want to collect title of a given slide (then I will make a loop).
But I have no **Item** property in **Slides** object.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
...
namespace TestTaskPane
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
    ...
      public string CollectTitles
      {
           Slide Sld = this.Application.ActivePresentation.Slides.Item(1)
      }
```

I have the following error:
'Slides' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

But if have a look to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.slides_members(v=office.14).aspx) I can see Slides has an Item property.

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a normal array iteration on `Slides` object, please see the example below.

```
var p = this.Application.ActivePresentation; //your presentation

var titles = new List<Shape>();

for (int i = 0; i < p.Slides.Count; i++)
{
   titles.Add(p.Slides[i].Shapes.Title);
}
```

Comment: You are right, I can directly access to each Slide using this.Application.ActivePresentation.Slides[i]. I still don't understand why Item does not work, but with your advice I don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Application.ActivePresentation.Slides[0]` instead of
`Application.ActivePresentation.Slides.Items(0)`. With Slides[0] you say get Slides.this[0] which is exactly what the Item property stands for.

Edited to try to explain why you can directly access the Slides property.